# Is there some idiom for telling someone specialised knowledge is not required to understand the situation?

Tags: idioms

I’m searching for an idiom that would mean the following: The situation is obvious to an untrained eye.

For example, say someone looked unwell, perhaps with a cold and one person says to another about a third party,

> "You don’t require a doctor to understand that he has a cold, because
>   it’s ____________ [obvious to an untrained eye as to what is going
>   on]".

Thank you!

Comment: Hey, that's no rocket science. It's not brain surgery, you know.

Comment: Your commented suggestions are better than my answer.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278272/how-to-say-its-not-rocket-science-before-rockets-existed/278309#278309

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiom meaning to talk about something everyone already knows](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/422382/246019).

Comment: I think the answers have what you are looking for, but none of them will fit into the sentence you provided.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: "Layman"... a person without specialized training.  "A layman could understand ..."

Answer (score 17):

**It's not rocket science**
or
**It's not brain surgery**

These are often used when someone is trying to make something more difficult than it really is.

From the OED:

> [**brain surgery**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/22536?redirectedFrom=brain+surgery#eid115196761)  n. surgery performed on the brain, neurosurgery; (hence humorously) something requiring a high level of intelligence or expertise (frequently in negative constructions, implying that something is not difficult); cf. rocket science n. at rocket n.5
>
> [**rocket science**](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/166731#eid25162383) n.  (a) the science of rockets and rocket propulsion;  (b) colloq. something requiring a high level of intelligence or expertise; frequently in negative constructions, implying that something is relatively simple.

Comment: Or sometimes... it's not rocket surgery.

Comment: Dammit, Smithers, this isn't rocket science, it's brain surgery!

Comment: Also "you don't have to be a rocket scientist / brain surgeon."

Comment: I know it *is* used as an idiom like this, but "rocket science" annoys me.  "Rocket science is not hard, you can explain most of it to a bright 8-year-old.  Rocket *engineering* on the other hand..."

Comment: Back in a school's rocket club I was in, a common phrase was, "it's only rocket surgery!"

Comment: @RobertColumbia Relevant: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=THNPmhBl-8I

Comment: @Kevin: That was gold!

Answer (score 10):

One such idiom is: ***no-brainer***.

> "You don’t require a doctor to understand that he has a cold, because
>   it’s ***a no-brainer***".

TFD(idioms):

> **[no-brainer](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/no-brainer)**
>   *n*. an easy question that takes no thinking to answer; a simple problem that requires no intellect to solve; a dilemma that requires
>   no pondering to resolve.
>
> McGraw-Hill's Dictionary of American Slang and Colloquial Expressions
>   Copyright © 2006 by The McGraw-Hill Companies, Inc. All rights
>   reserved.

Answer (score 5):

I propose ***common sense***. It has a generally positive connotation.

> **common sense**
>
> *n.*  Sound judgment not based on specialized knowledge.

<sup><sup>American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved from https://www.thefreedictionary.com/common+sense</sup></sup>

Comment: I think the most common form for the specific example used by the OP would be "it's just common sense."

Answer (score 2):

***Any Fool***

In England this is an idiomatic expression for "a person with the minimum level of skill and knowledge that everyone should have".

*Any fool can see..*

- *You don’t require a doctor to understand that he has a cold, any fool can see that*
- *Any fool can see he has a cold, you don't need to be a brain surgeon.*

*Any fool knows...*

- *Any fool knows you have to turn it on first*

*Any fool can...*

- *Any fool can hit his thumb with a hammer, but it takes someone special to hit his head.*

Answer (score 1):

1. It's easy as ABC.

Source : [idioms.thefreedictionary.com](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/easy+as+ABC) (note the word intuitive.)

Answer (score 1):

It's **[plain as day](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/as-clear-plain-as-day)**. The expression *plain as day* means that it is obvious, simple to recognize or understand, straightforward. That is to say, if you can recognize daytime or see the sun in the sky, then you will recognize something that is *plain as day*.

> It's as plain as day that he has a cold.

Answer (score 0):

"A monkey could (do/see) it." This is probably a little more common with "do" instead of "see", but it works either way.